# Make a custom_post translatable

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, php, categories

I have a problem with two plugins.

The 1st plugin adds a custom_post type whenever a post is created.
The 2nd plugin is a translator and only shows posttypes that are translatable (according to the creator)

I build a custom widget that shows posts from two different post_types. The usual posts as WP provides and the custom posts.

The problem is that the 1st plugin with the custom_post type doesn't show the posts when the 2nd plugin is activated. After contacting the plugin owner he states that it is because the custom_post type isn't translatable.

I googled my ass of how to make a custom_post type translatable but I couldn't find how to do this. (or I'm just stupid)

Here is my Query code that collects the posts.

```
    $wpcust = new WP_Query( 
        array( 
            'post_type' => array(
                'custom_post',
                'post'
            ),   
            'cat'=>'-35,-42,-39,-43,-41,-40,-52',
            'showposts' => '4',
            'suppress_filters' => false, 
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key' => 'intern',
                    'value' => ' '
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'intern',
                    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                )
            )   
         ) 
        );
```

The query excludes certain categories.
and checks if the post is for internal use or not.

M.

- UPDATE- 
  Excuse me for being an idiot.
  It was just a setting in the 2nd plugin to activate the custom_post type